# How do I 'inherit' a class properties to use with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I want to add a new property on my class, make it strongly typed so I can use it in my views and controllers, I've tried to inherit the properties, but Entity Framework or C# throws me errors...

I have this class:

```
 public class Patient
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    .....
 }
```

which has a lot more properties in it, but shortened here.

I have a razor view, which is uses 'Patient' as it's model

```
using model Project.Models.Patient
```

So I had completed my view (or so I thought) and was asked to add functionality in the view. The functionality is to send a POST using a form of a 'Message' (a simple textarea in html). I've already got all the details I want, but this new 'Message'

So I thought, because I don't want this field in the database I could add it like this:

```
 public class Patient
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    .....
 }
```

But I'm not a fan of this, it doesn't relate to the Patient in any other way.

So I thought I could  change my model in razor to something like this:

```
@model Project.Models.DTOs.PatientMessage
```

and inherit the Patient class and all it's properties (so I don't have to retype and copy past the fields again) and the new PatientMessage class would look like this:

```
public class PatientMessage : Patient
{
   public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

But when I refresh my application, I receive a message stating the Application Database Context has changed, and I have to update this. I don't want to update my database, and I can't really see why I need to, it's an extra field which I don't want to include in my database.

So then I decided to make this class an 'abstract' class

```
public abstract class PatientMessage : Patient
{
   public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

When I refreshed my page this time, I saw no need to update the Database, great I thought, and when I went near a page where the model was

```
@model Project.Models.Patient
```

I received this message

> The abstract type 'Project.Models.DTOs.PatientMessage' has no mapped descendants and so cannot be mapped. Either remove 'Project.Models.DTOs.PatientMessage' from the model or add one or more types deriving from 'Project.Models.DTOs.PatientMessage' to the model.

**MY QUESTION**
Can I include this one field, without placing it on the Patient class, ideally without having to update models in my razor views, or would I have to change the models in the views and controllers and update the information to include the message and map all the details from a 'PatientMessage' to a 'Patient'

Please let me know if you need any further information.

Regards

Comment: There are only two reliable ways: Either you inherit that Property and override it, wich has to be allowed by the base class. Or you encapsualte the base class, at wich point you have a custom class with full code control. The MVVM pattern calls for a lot Encapsulation of Model Classes into ViewModel Classes you can work with for exactly such reasons.

Comment: Ideally, your DTOs should not inherit from your models. They only need to represent the data that's coming into (or from) your controllers/actions as objects. If you insist on inheriting from your `Patient` model, you'll have to explicitly ignore the created DTO, either using an `[Ignore]` attribute or calling `Ignore()` in your `OnModelCreating()` method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn237192(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: The simplest and most logical approach is to use containment instead of inheritance, i.e. treat patient message as combination of patient and message. e.g. `public class PatientMessage { public Patient Patient { get; set; } public string Message { get; set; } }`